# Passing parameters to Extension Controller for test

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller, controller-extension

I have a Extension Controller which gets back a different set of Opportunities based on the value of HTTP parameter named `display` sent in. So my code is as such:

```
public OpportunityListExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {
    // blank constructor
}

public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    String display = pageRef.getParameters().get('display');
    String whereclause = '';
    if (display == (LOST)) {
        ...
    } else if (display.equals(INACTIVE)) {
        ...
```

Based on the the value of `display` I return different Opportunities. Works great but I need a unit test for this and I am not sure how to pass in the display value to the controller.

Here is my test:

```
@isTest
public static void testOpportunityListExtension() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.Opportunities;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);  
    // create an opp
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(name='testOpp');
    opp.stageName = 'Closed Won';
    opp.CloseDate = Date.today() - 4;
    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
    opps.add(opp);
    insert opps;

    ApexPages.StandardSetController sc = 
             new ApexPages.StandardSetController(new Opportunity[]{});
    //
    // ?????? Not sure how to pass in display value
    OpportunityListExtension ole = new OpportunityListExtension(sc);
    List<Opportunity> oppsFromController = ole.getOpportunities();        

    System.assertEquals(1, oppsFromController.size());
    Opportunity oppportunity = opps.get(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `getParameters()` returns a `Map<String, String>` to which you can add items.
In your test you can use something like this:

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.Opportunities;
pageRef.getParameters().put('display', 'INACTIVE');
```

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer did not work for me in my Custom Controller. 
[Somewhere else](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35116/how-do-i-call-a-vf-page-with-parameters-in-a-unit-test) I saw something that did work:

```
PageReference pr = Page.MyCustomPagename;
Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', x.Id);
system.assertEquals(x.Id, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
```