# How do I call a VF page with parameters in a Unit Test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a public page (http://uat-savantsystems.cs30.force.com/Customers/five9xmlresponder) which accepts two parameters. I attempt to call the page in my test class with the parameters as such:

```
PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('http://uat-savantsystems.cs30.force.com/Customers/five9xmlresponder');
vfPage.getParameters().put('pin', '1111111111');
vfPage.getParameters().put('cid', '2222222');
```

With no luck, in debug, param1 and 2 are null, so I tried the following:

```
PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('http://uat-savantsystems.cs30.force.com/Customers/five9xmlresponder?param1=1111111111&param2=2222222');
```

and ended up with the same results.

My custom controller is called by a VF page URL. Based on the parameters, the VF page displays different XML.

It seems like the VF page just isn't getting called by the test class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me, I hope it helps!

```
  PageReference tpageRef = Page.NameOfYourPageHere;
  Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', po.Id);

  System.assertEquals( po.id,ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the test framework know about your page so it can set the current page on your controller by using:

```
 Test.setCurrentPage(vfPage);
```

See [Test Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm).